# Associate Elastic IP while creating an EC2 Instance using Node.js

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk

Is there a way I can specify an `existing Elastic IP` in the `Lambda` function that creates an instance of a `Windows Server`?

I am looking at the documentation at http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/EC2.html#runInstances-property but i do not see any mention of Elastic IP assignment.

Answer (score 0):

Elastic IP addresses can only be assigned to an EC2 instance after it has been launched.

1. Use `runInstances` to launch your EC2 instance and retrieve the EC2 instance ID.
2. Use `associateAddress` to assign your Elastic IP address to your EC2 instance.